# Standard data for countries, nationalities, state/province, currencies, time zone

Tags: dataset, iso

Where can I get International Standard dataset of:

- Countries
- Nationalities
- State/Province
- Currencies
- Time Zone

With **foreign key** as Countries.

Comment: This info is obviously all available from separate sources but would have to be combined.  For example, CIA World Factbook has a lot of this information but doesn't use ISO country names and seems to be missing Aland Islands and maybe more.